# Login redirect in jsp project

Tags: jsp

I've some issue for redirecting admin page. I've **index.jsp** which  I'm login in there and I've **admin.jsp** which doing admin stuff. The problem is when I'm redirecting index.jsp to admin.jsp I'm getting 404 error.

```
<input type="button" value="ADMIN LOGIN" class="btn btn-sm" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"></p></div>
<div id="id01" class="modal">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
         <form class="modal-content animate" action="/admin.jsp">
            <div class="container" class="text-center" align="center">
                <label for="uName"><b>User Name</b></label>
                <input id="userName" type="text" placeHolder="Enter Username" name="uname"  required>
                <br>
                <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input id="password" type="password" placeHolder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm" onclick="login()">Login</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="btn btn-sm">Cancel</button>
                <br>
            </div>

         </form>
</div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
function login(){
    var URL="http://localhost:8983/solr/adminCore/select?q=userName:";
    var userName= $("#userName").val();
    var password= $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'json.wrf',
        success: function (data){
            var docs=data.response.docs;
            if(userName==docs.userName && password==docs.password)
                {
                    window.location.href("/?admin.jsp");
                }
            else
                {
                window.alert("Error");
                }
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

My codes like that. Am I doing something wrong? How I solve it?
And my project has not **web.xml**